# Javascript fontcolor() function does not work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the fontcolor() function on one of the variables in my function. At first I was trying it on a number variable and realized that the function only works on String variables. I type-casted the variable using toString(), yet no luck! Pls help1

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
var totalCost = toString(numberOfBuckets * costOfBucket);                    
alert(typeof totalCost); //String            
alert(totalCost.fontcolor("red")); //Undefined object
```

Comment: By "Undefined object", are you getting the string `"undefined"` or the `"[object Undefined]"`?

Comment: I think you are looking for `(numberOfBuckets * costOfBucket).toString()` or `String(numberOfBuckets * costOfBucket)`.

Comment: Oh yes you are right! I got the syntax totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var totalCost = "" + (numberOfBuckets * costOfBucket);
```

instead of

```
var totalCost = toString(numberOfBuckets * costOfBucket);
```

Code:

```
var numberOfBuckets = 10;
var costOfBucket = 20;

var totalCost = '' + numberOfBuckets * costOfBucket;                    
alert(totalCost.fontcolor("red")); // <font color="red">200</font>
```